# Can I block a certain website from Google results?

Tags: google-search

Whenever I need to know a simple fact, Google often finds it in answers.com.

I loathe answers.com's user interface, and inability to deliver the information I need after I click through Google, requiring additional work to actually get the answer.

I'm signed into Google; is there a way to tell Google I don't want results that include answers.com without adding `-answers.com` in the search phrase?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chrome, there is a Chrome extension that does this. It is called *Personal Blocklist*, it's developed by Google, and it is [available from the Chrome Web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef).

As this is a browser extension, your blocked sites settings are not available to other browsers. If you use multiple computers, you could sync your Google Chrome profile, and your list of blocked sites will be synced along with it.

Comment: This is no longer available, any other ideas?